# Responsive global font size on Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation

The global font size in foundation-6 is `16px` and can be altered in `_settings.scss`. Is there a way to make this size varies depending on the screen width? I want to decrease this size to `13px` for `small` screens. I know there is something like that for the headers but I am asking here for the global size. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase font size for mobiles in Foundation 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591238/increase-font-size-for-mobiles-in-foundation-6)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably look to add a set of media queries to your app.scss file to set the font size for each breakpoint. This make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (feel free to use Foundation's function to convert the value in px to rem or em):

```
body{
 font-size:13px;
 @include breakpoint(medium) {
   font-size:$global-font-size;
 }
}
```