# Increase font size for mobiles in Foundation 6

Tags: media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm unable to make the following `SCSS` increase the `font-size` on `mobiles` and `tablets`:

```sass
// Mobile

@include breakpoint(medium down) {
    $global-font-size: 200%;
}
```

The generated `CSS` files isn't even changed after adding the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to define a SASS variable inside a media query. See [this Closed issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1639) for a more detailed description (has Foundation as an example).

You can do a similar kind of thing like this though:

```
%screen-font {
    font-size: 100%;

    @media #{$medium-down} {
        font-size: 200% !important;
    }
}

html {
    @extend %screen-font;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is to replace `$global-font-size` with `font-size`:

```sass
// Mobile

html {
    @include breakpoint(medium down) {
        font-size: 200% !important;
    }
}
```